# corrupted file by saving with CodeIgniter and header output

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to download a file from the upload folder by calling mydomein/download/filenem

It works in this way, that I received the wanted image, but I think I have a bug in the header which I output into my controller with this code:

```
$file=my_path_tofile;

header('Expires: 0');
         header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
         header("Content-type: ".$finfo->file($file));  
         //header("Content-type: application/".$ext);
         header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");  
         header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$data['realname'].'"');
         header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
         header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
         header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
         header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
         readfile($file);
         exit;
```

If I call the URL, the download will start, the filename is fine and the size looks right too. But if I want to open the file I get the message that the file could not open in cases of corruption.

I'm not an expert about headers, so can someone explain me what is the problem is and how I can solve it?

Comment: What have yout ried to debug the problem? It should not be that hard to open the file in a text editor to check for differences to the original file

Comment: @NicoHaase i cannot use a textfile, i could only use images, if i open this into a editor i see hieroglyphics. I trie to play around with the headers, but all settings wont work.

Comment: what's in here `$file=my_path_tofile;` ? show us the file path